# Cómo hacer que una función en Jquery se ejecute sólo sobre el elemento clickado

Tags: jquery, funciones, selectores

estoy maquetando una web que contiene una gran cantidad de artículos. Para hacerlo de forma eficiente está maquetada con clases en css. Quiero hacer que cuando se pinche sobre el título del artículo se despliegue más información sobre el mismo. El código de Jquery funciona, pero el problema es que despliega la información de todos los artículos, no sólo la información de el artículo clickado. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Adjunto el código de esta función:

```
$(".caja").click(function () {
    $(".cajacompleta").slideDown("slow");
    $(".cajacompleta").css("display", "flex");
});

$(".volverapapers").click(function () {
    $(".cajacompleta").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Bueno... despliega todos porque tú le has pedido que despliegue todos! Prueba a buscar el componente `.cajacompleta` que es hijo del elemento que ha sido clicado (`$(this)`)en vez de buscar todos los elementos de esa clase.

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta Benito, lo que no sé es cómo hacerlo exactamente porque .cajacompleta es un div a continuación de .caja, no se encuentra dentro (esto es así para poder maquetarlo cómo quiero). Entiendo que si uso $(this) podría mostrar un elemento hijo, pero cómo puedo hacer que muestre el siguiente div al clickado?

Comment: Lo más fácil entonces, sería añadir un contenedor a ambos `div`. De esa manera puedes acceder a través del `parent()` del `$(this)`, y usar `find()` para acceder al que te interesa. Otra manera, si el `.cajacompleta` es justo lo siguiente de `.caja`, puedes usar [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/). Te recomiendo acostumbrarte a leer la documentación y buscar por ella. Pues te acabarás pasando horas y horas haciéndolo, cuanto antes te acostumbres a navegar por documentación antes verás todo lo que te estás perdiendo :)

Comment: Gracias! Con next() pude solucionarlo bastante bien!

Comment: Me alegra ver que lo solucionaste, siéntete libre de poner una respuesta explicando la solución y añadiendo el código necesario, así más usuarios podrán beneficiarse de la pregunta y tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue separar el contenido a desplegar en un segundo , quedando algo así:

```
 <div class="caja">
 <figure><img src="../img/Barco.jpg" alt=""></figure>
 </div>

<div class="cajacompleta">
<figure><img src="../img/Barco.jpg" alt=""></figure>
<h3>Título del artículo</h3>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"</p>
<h4>Autor</h4>
<a class="leerpaper" href="#">Read Paper</a>
<button class="volverapapers"> Back to papers</button>
</div>
```

Las siguientes funciones sirven para abrir la caja completa, la cual es el elemento a continuación de .caja, y ".volverapapers" vuelve a cerrar la ventana.

```
$(".caja").click(function () {
$(this).next().slideDown("slow");
});

$(".volverapapers").click(function () {
$(".cajacompleta").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Como te dicen en los comentarios, estás haciendo referencia a todos los elementos de la clase. Una posible solución sería esta:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Creamos el evento sobre todos los elementos de clase 'caja'.
  $(document).on('click', '.caja', (e) => {
    
    // Obtenemos el elemento afectado.
    let $el = $(e.currentTarget);

    // Aquí hacemos referencia a todos los elementos de clase 'caja'.
    $('.caja').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    
    // Aquí solamente al elemento donde el usuario ha hecho 'click'.
    $el.css('background-color', 'red');
  
  });

});
```

```css
.caja {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
    <div class='caja'>1</div>
    <div class='caja'>2</div>
    <div class='caja'>3</div>
    <div class='caja'>4</div>
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!